# Python Poloniex Websocket Call

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, websocket

I am getting an 'Invalid nonce in payload' error when connecting via web socket to poloniex exchange!

I have tried various ways to encode the payload but I don't seem to be able to get around the error. I know my nonce works as I have used the same one with public API methods.

```
import websocket
import threading
import time
import json
import codecs
import hmac 
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import hashlib

Key = 'KEY HERE'
sign = 'SECRET HERE'

def on_message(ws, message):
    json_msg = json.loads(message)
    print(json_msg)

def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)

def on_close(ws):
    print("### closed ###")


def on_open(ws):
    print("ON OPEN")
    def run(*args):
        nonce = int(round(time.time()-599900000)*100)
        hashed = hmac.new(Sign.encode(), digestmod=hashlib.sha512)
        sign = hashed.hexdigest()
        ws.send(json.dumps({'command':'subscribe','channel':'1000','key':Key,'payload':nonce,'sign':sign}))

    threading.Thread(target=run).start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://api2.poloniex.com/",
                              on_message = on_message,
                              on_error = on_error,
                              on_close = on_close)

    ws.on_open = on_open
    ws.run_forever()
```

I expect to see the output of the data as described in the poloniex API documentation https://docs.poloniex.com/#websocket-api

PS: You will need to use your own API from the exchange to run this script!

Comment: Can you add the error response to your question

Comment: The error I was getting is listed is in the first part of my question. I was getting an 'Invalid nonce in payload' error but I think it's because I omitted the nonce= parameter when passing the request. I have now included this and no longer get the invalid nonce error but get permission denied error..not sure what I am doing wrong here? ```nonce = int(time.time())
                                  nonce = 'nonce={}'.format(nonce)```

Comment: As per the doc its quoted as "current epoch time in milliseconds is an easy choice for nonce value".
You can try using below login to get epoch time in milliseconds
nonce = int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.today().timetuple())) * 100